# Multi-Monitor Taskbars for Windows 7

Tags: window-manager, windows-7

I'm looking for a program allowing Multi-Monitor Taskbars in Windows with the following features:

- works Windows 7 (Windows 8 has it [natively](https://superuser.com/q/495874/116475) anyway)
- supports at least 6 monitors
- if I open a program through the start menu in monitor X, the program should open in monitor X
- eats as little CPU as possible
- has GUI
- free is preferred
- as responsive as possible
- as bug-free as possible

[DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/Features/) is pretty good but I'm looking for alternatives as I have some issues it. ([Issue 1](http://www.displayfusion.com/Discussions/View/is-displayfusion-supposed-to-take-almost-half-a-core-of-the-cpu-i7-3rd-gen/?ID=cc838dc7-b682-41fd-b497-2343b3ce40df); [Issue 2](http://www.displayfusion.com/Discussions/View/upside-down-task-bar-on-wake-up/?ID=74c75f1c-680d-4eff-8912-66a7e0ee9cea), [Issue 3](http://www.displayfusion.com/Discussions/View/1-second-to-move-the-window-from-the-primary-monitor-to-the-monitor-where-i-used-the-task-bar-to-launch-it/?ID=0629f426-835b-4dfe-9892-747401a794b4); and it is non-free)

Answer (score 5):

You could take a look at [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) by Realsoft. This meets and exceeds all of your requirements other than cost but there is a [30 day trial](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/download.asp) version available so you can test it out beforehand:

- supports Windows 7 (32 and 64 bit)
- supports every monitor detected by Windows
- plethora of options to determine where windows launch
- relatively light on resources
- has a full GUI to configure it

There is also a tour [showing and explaining each of the features](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/).

Ultramon also provides [the functionality you're requesting in your other question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1754/program-to-switch-two-windows-in-windows).