# Program to switch two windows between two monitors in Windows

Tags: window-manager, windows-7

I'm looking for a program that would allow me to switch two windows between two monitors by mouse clicks and/or keyboard with as few clicks and/or key strokes as possible.

For example, program A is on monitor 1 and program B is on monitor 2. If I want to switch the location of program A and program B, I just want to have to left-click on program A then left-click on program B, then hitting some keyboard shortcut to have them switch.

It should have the following features:

- works Windows 7
- supports at least 6 monitors
- eats as little CPU as possible
- free is preferred
- as responsive as possible
- as bug-free as possible

Comment: Windows 7 already has a feature that is very close to what you need: [you can use shift+win+arrow to move the active window to a different screen](http://lifehacker.com/5526025/make-the-most-of-your-multiple-monitors-in-windows-7)

Comment: @Michiel thanks for the link, this is indeed close, but most of the time I switch two windows, so having a shortcut dedicated to this would be faster.

Comment: The application I have suggested to your [other question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1801/305) also provides functionality to complete this with customisable hotkeys and/or mouse clicks.

Answer (score 4):

This kind of ad-hoc task tends to be best solved by a generic automation framework to provide basic building blocks (e.g. commands to retrieve window geometries and move windows around), with a small script that implements your specific requirement.

On Windows, [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) is a general-purpose desktop automation scripting environment for Windows. It's open source. The scripting language makes Basic look not so bad, but it gets the job done.

Here's a script which switches the position of two windows. It works the way you describe: click on one window, switch to another window, and these two windows will be transposed. The script binds the action to the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>; change the `^!f::` line to pick the [hotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) you prefer. After installing AutoHotkey, save this script to a file called `flip-windows.ahk` (the name isn't significant, only the extension is) and add it to your startup scripts (or run it once to test; there's an icon in the task bar with an exit command).

```
;; Switch the position and size of the active window with the one immediately after in
;; top-to-bottom z-order.
;; This action is bound to the hotkey Ctrl+Alt+F.

#NoEnv
#SingleInstance force

;; Bind the action to Ctrl+Alt+F
^!f::

;; Set id1 to the window ID of the active window
WinGet, id1, ID, A
;; Set id2 to the window ID of the next active window (the one that Alt+Tab would
;; switch to). To do this, iterate over the active windows in top-to-bottom order.
;; This order is: first permanently-raised windows, then the active window, then
;; the next active window.
WinGet, ids, List
Loop, %ids%
{
  current := ids%A_Index%
  IfNotEqual, current, %id1%, Continue
  next_index := A_Index + 1
  id2 := ids%next_index%
  Break
}


;; Retrieve the coordinates of the two windows
WinGetPos, x1, y1, w1, h1, ahk_id %id1%
WinGetPos, x2, y2, w2, h2, ahk_id %id2%

;WinGetTitle title1, ahk_id %id1%
;WinGetTitle title2, ahk_id %id2%
;MsgBox %id1% "%title1%" %w1%x%h1%+%x1%+%y1% <-> %id2% "%title2%" %w2%x%h2%+%x2%+%y2%

;; Move the two windows to each other's coordinates
WinMove, ahk_id %id1%, , %x2%, %y2%, %w2%, %h2%
WinMove, ahk_id %id2%, , %x1%, %y1%, %w1%, %h1%
Return
```

If you just want to send a window to another monitor, [Windows 7 has this built-in](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts#keyboard-shortcuts=windows-7) (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>), but if that's not exactly what you want you may be able to build something better with AHK (some sample AHK scripts may inspire you, e.g. [1](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/63931-another-multi-monitor-window-mover/)).