# Multiple monitors with all features on each

Tags: windows-7, display, multi-monitor

I tried the tutorials [Make the Most of Your Multiple Monitors in Windows](http://lifehacker.com/5526025/make-the-most-of-your-multiple-monitors-in-windows-7), [How to Set Up Multiple Monitors with Windows 7](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-set-up-multiple-monitors-with-windows-7.html), and [Max Out the Multi-Monitor Magic Under Windows 7](http://www.howtogeek.com/60758/).

At present, only my main screen has desktop icons, Start Menu, etc.

How do I acquire one for each monitor? Is [UltraMon](https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) (superlatively) recommended?

Comment: Hello LePressentiment, I added the [tag:windows-7] tag (because of the linked tutorials). If you need this for a different Windows version, please [edit] your question and retag it accordingly.

Comment: Closely related: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1753/903

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Actual Multiple Monitors](http://www.actualtools.com/multiplemonitors/):

- non-free
- Windows 7
- Mirror Taskbar with start button and notification area

[image]

I don't believe it can mirror icons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [UltraMon](https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) (non-free, works with Windows 7) to mirror the taskbar, but it won't mirror the 'start' menu or the notification area, and it doesn't have the option to mirror the icons:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/) (non-free, works with Windows 7) to mirror the taskbar, and it will mirror the 'start' menu as well as the notification area, but it doesn't have the option to mirror the icons.

[image]

FYI DisplayFusion contains [a few minor issues](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1753/903), and DisplayFusion can be used along with UltraMon (that's what I do to take the most of each one).